# Convert array in a variable and manipulate it to create XML file in php

Tags: php, xml, explode, preg-split

```
    $bday = $f['date_of_birth']; //it outputs-> 20102016
```

So I tried using preg_split() or even explode() but was of no help

```
    $str = $bday;
    $chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($chars[0]);
```

I want to use $bday as a nodeValue in DOMDocument to create XML file

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $doc->createElement('StudentDetails');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    $ele1 = $doc->createElement('DateOfBirth');
    $ele1->nodeValue=$bday;
    $root->appendChild($ele1);
```

I want my XML output to be like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <StudentDetails>
         <DateOfBirth>20/10/2016</DateOfBirth>
    </StudentDetails>
```

Comment: @RathnaKumaran $bday = 20102016

Comment: Might I suggest an edit to the title: "How to format a string containing a date?" As the current title doesn't accurately describe what you're asking about.

Comment: As an aside, if I were you I will use XMLWriter instead of DOMDocument to produce your xml document in a lighter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is always `DDMMYYYY` you could insert slashes with preg_replace.

```
$bday = preg_replace('/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/', "$1/$2/$3", $bday);
```

Comment: better still `$bday = preg_replace('/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/', "$1/$2/$3", trim($f['date_of_birth']));`

clearer regex, clean input, and one less variable

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using RegExps for this. Not only is the DateTime class meant for this purpose, which makes it immediately clear for anyone reading the code what it is supposed to do; But it is also more robust, as it recognizes a host of different formats, wheres this RegExp will fail on the slightest of changes in the birthdate pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The magic of [the DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to the rescue!

```
$dtz = new DateTimeZone ("UTC");
$birthdate = new DateTime ($f['dateofbirth'], $dtz);
echo $birthdate->format ("d/m/Y");
```

If you want to do some calculations on time, then you might need to set the correct timezone for your location. If not, then UTC should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` function for convert date to your format. Within the function you have to provide current format. finally you have to provide you expected format (`$date->format('d/m/Y')`).

```
$bday = '20102016';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY',$bday);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change `$f['date_of_birth']` to 20 10 2016. Then just use:

```
$chars = explode(" ",$bday);
```

Then you have an array with this values: `{20,10,2016}`